# Recovering a lost file system off a hard drive?

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, gparted

I was repartioning my hard drive, and I was in the process of moving a partition left and resizing it, when I accidentally hit the "Cancel" button. While the partition itself was already resized, the moving of the file system itself had not begun moving (it was in a 'read-only' phase of the process at the time), and so I am still hopeful that it is still possible to recover the file system, and that everything should be intact. However, it is inaccessible by any means I can think of, and located somewhere in the middle of the new partition, though I don't know exactly where.

Is there any tools I could use to find the location of the file system or recover it or really, just anything to get access to my files there? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have used the instructions on this link with great success many times.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Tips:
Always make a full image of the entire drive, then perform any relevant recovery efforts on the **image**.

Also, if you can, use a 10,000 RPM drive (Western Digital Raptor) or a SSD for holding the image during recovery - it will speed up your recovery efforts quite a bit.

Does that help?

Comment: Firstly, I have already had a look at that page, and tried some of the solutions there, though noone seemed to work properly. I think that the gpart program might work, but I have had some problems compiling it myself. It seems to work now, however, so if I'm lucky, that'll get me somewhere. Secondly, is it really necessary to make an image of the whole drive? I am currently half-way through making an image of the partition which I know holds my lost file system, which by itself takes 8 hours to copy, and making an image of the whole drive sure would take a lot longer, nearly a day, to do.

Comment: These things always take a few hours. The Foremost, Sleuth, and Autopsy kits mentioned on the DataRecovery page are pretty powerful. I doubt you will lose data if you are careful in your recovery efforts.